# File System API using IBM Worklight

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am creating an android mobile app.

I am trying to create a screen that would contain a text box, check box and a submit button.

Each time, when a user clicks the submit button, the data in the text box and the check box should be captured in a csv file and gets stored in the android mobile device.

I am done with the creation of text box, check box and the button. I am stuck with the file concepts of creating a csv file and storing them on the mobile device

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the Cordova File System API in order to create the required file and enter data into it. If you've already started implementing, share your implementation code so that it could be examined.

See here for the documentation: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md